# Using Paperclip to direct upload files to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

so I've got paperclip set up with uploadify to upload things to S3.  I have made my setup so that stuff gets loaded directly to S3 and then when it's done I post to my webserver the results...

All I get back is the file name and size.  am I supposed to build my own processor or before_post_process method to "download" the file from S3 in order to process it? or am I missing something and uploadify should have provided me a stream with the file inside it after it was done posting to S3?

How do you guys go about direct uploads to S3 and then notifying your paperclip backed model?  Do you have to pull files from the server and do post-processing on them or will paperclip handle all of that?

Comment: what do you mean "direct upload?" With paperclip the upload passes through your webserver, right? So you have the file, in memory or in tmp/. How/When do you "post the results to the webserver"?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can bypass the webserver all together and just use Paperclip to do image processing and object management.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a couple blog posts describing how to do it...

http://www.railstoolkit.com/posts/uploading-files-directly-to-amazon-s3-using-fancyupload

http://www.railstoolkit.com/posts/fancyupload-amazon-s3-uploader-with-paperclip

They use FancyUploader (which uses MooTools/Flash) to upload directly to S3, bypassing Heroku and their dreaded 30 second request timeout all together, and then use DelayedJob to queue up post-processing tasks like thumbnailing and PaperClip to do the actual processing of the files.

If I can get this working with CarrierWave, I will post up a project on GitHub to share (in a week or so once I get time)

**Update**:

Sample project using Rails 3, Flash and MooTools-based FancyUploader to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-FancyUploader

Sample project using Rails 3, Flash/Silverlight/GoogleGears/BrowserPlus and jQuery-based Plupload to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-Plupload

I will add the post-processing example once I have time.

Comment: you do not want do to this with flash!

Btw, this works perfectly on heroku without flash, sounds like you haven't even tried.

Comment: 1) You can't use an HTML5 uploader to access S3 since they don't allow it quite yet.  They have other uploaders like `plupload` that you can use Silverlight, Google Gears, etc. to upload with as well if you're uncomfortable with Flash.  2) I have a working example on Heroku using 2 different kinds of uploaders.  I plan on posting the code up here once I am done with them.  3) Try and be helpful instead of just being impolite.

Comment: You give the impression that upload is difficult on heroku and one need other solution than plain paperclip/carrierwave, which is false. This is helpful to others that otherwise could be mislead into chosing something they don't need, IMO. S3 needs secret keys, bypassing the server (this is the objective right?) requires the secret to be held by flash or whatever (are there other options?). I discourages using flash for this.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of a couple things:  1) Uploading on Heroku is only difficult for large files since Heroku has a 30 second request timeout so doing large files that first have to go through the server (as is the case with normal implementation of Paperclip and CarrierWave) is out of the question since the request times out before the upload is complete. 2) You never share your secret key (or at least you never should). What you do instead is create an S3 policy with a signature that has been signed with your secret key which gets passed along to Amazon.

Comment: Flash never knows about your secret key because you hold all of that information in your Rails app.  You never expose anything.  If you're only discouraging Flash for those reasons you list, you may want to reconsider.

Comment: Any chance you ever made the post-processing example?

Comment: @jBeas Sorry, no :(  There is a lot of info out there about that though: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki , http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/a-gentle-introduction-to-carrierwave/ , http://www.williambharding.com/blog/rails/howto-create-a-custom-thumbnail-processor-in-carrierwave/

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a processor or use the callback methods but the file will definitively be on your server before going to S3.

If you are in the callback method for example you can access it using something like:

```
self.file.to_file
```

Once that is done processing and uploading the file will be deleted from your server. You don't need to do anything to notify or post process. Paperclip will handle it.