# Rails + Paperclip on Heroku is very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using combination Heroku + Amazon S3 + Paperclip gem for uploading files. It's working, but the upload itself is very slow.

I've tried to buy an extra dyno and a little bit updated the model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :album

  attr_accessible :caption, :title, :image, :image_file_name, :user_id, :album_id


  has_attached_file :image,
                    :styles => { :tiny => '100x100>', 
                                 :original => "900x900>" },
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:user_id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :url  => ":s3_eu_url"

  process_in_background :image
end
```

This is working pretty fast on Heroku, but: I choose a file to upload, hit the button Upload and within a few seconds is the page refreshed. I don't see the uploaded image itself, because is not uploaded yet. But process on the background will upload it.
When I refresh the page like 2-4 seconds later, I correctly to see the uploaded image.

But this is not very user-friendly way to do it.
How to quickly upload an image to Heroku with using Paperclip and delayed job? What am I missing to correctly set it up?

Thanks

Comment: Research direct upload to s3

Answer (score 0):

Try a new Gem called [CarrierWaveDirect](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct) it allows you to upload files direct to S3 using a html form and easily move the image processing into a background process

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to avoid the time needed from when you finished upload from pc to the time finished processing (and/or copying to s3) from the user perspective

The best you can do is improve your UX but either displaying a message that the file has yet to finish processing and ask the user to return and try later.

That said, you can upload directly to s3 (but without paperclip, since thats your processor, and you need imagemagick on heroku servers (or any other servers) to process your styles.

see this [How do I upload direct to S3 with Paperclip has_attached_file connected to a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887573/how-do-i-upload-direct-to-s3-with-paperclip-has-attached-file-connected-to-a-mod)

and http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

It could quite a pain to handle all of this yourself when a little message to the user is all that takes care of your original problem (which is to improve user-friendlyness)

Answer (score 0):

1) You can change your s3 bucket location to US East as an additional solution if it's possible for your application. It will not completely fix issue, but will improve upload speed.

2) You can use s3_direct_upload for direct uploading to s3. http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and

Answer (score 0):

Lately I've preferred to do just in time image processing. Too many times I've used paperclip only to have front end requirements change during a redesign forcing me to reprocess all UG images in a batch job.

I created a simple gem suitable for use with rails that let's you proxy user uploaded images and process them on demand by changing url parameters: https://github.com/jcihocki/uncut

It accepts the same type of geometry strings you give in the :styles hash in paperclip. It's relatively new, but also pretty simple, and I am using it in production. Contributions also welcome.

Usage:

```
<%= $your_cdn_base_uri + processed_image_uri_for( "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/img.jpg", '100x100>' ) %>
```