# RoR, Paperclip and S3 - Defining content type dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I trying to create a file uploading model, which using Paperclip to help the user uploading HTML, CSS, JS and images to S3.

I got into an issue with CSS files, which are upload with "text/plain" content type.
I tried to change the "S3 Headers" on "before save" callback, but weirdly, it's only effects the next file uploaded (So the first file (e.g style.css) will be "text/plain" and the 2nd - "text/css", even if it's an image.

This is my code:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file, {
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3_credentials.yml",
                    :s3_permissions => :private,
                    :s3_headers => { 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=2592000', 'Expires' => 10.years.from_now.httpdate }
  }
  before_save :set_content_type

  def set_content_type
    mime_type = MIME::Types.type_for(self.file_file_name).first.to_s
    self.file.instance_write(:content_type, mime_type)
    self.file.options[:s3_headers]['Content-Type'] = mime_type
  end
end
```

Any idea of how to make the S3 Headers to work?

EDIT:
I've added `self.file.send :initialize_storage` into `set_content_type` method.

Now it's does works. But I'm still looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Checkout this question, this may help -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037418/using-paperclip-to-direct-upload-files-to-s3

Comment: Clearly, if what you are doing affects something then it somehow works. It just works on a wrong file. Try to add some logs inside your callback method and see the file name and mime_type you are getting. And you might need to add debug statements on your controller action to see what Asset is processed and in what order. A better way to debug such issues is with pry, but I am not sure whether you know how to use it.

Comment: Hi @Gen, I'm using pry and tailing my Rails server log, all  I can get is that the actual upload (Shows on tail as "paperclip info") is happening only after  the "before_save" actions. What I think is that I'm editing the Paperclip options, for the model. but since it already pass the init, it's not using the new options until the next instance creation.

Comment: @Kfir, what about after_save then? You can update it over there, or event after_commit.

Comment: @Kfir, you might also try before_validation. In this case it might not be overwritten.

Comment: @Gen, On after save the file is already uploaded, and before_validation didn't help as well. BUT - I figured out after inspecting the paperclip gem, that the Papacerclip::Attachment "new" action calling the s3 "initialize_storage" method, which is the only place I found which setting the s3 options . So adding  `self.file.send :initialize_storage` does working. I'm still waiting for better solution since it's a bit dirty..

Comment: @Kfir: ok, at least you found a way to hack it. I haven't worked with paperclip for a while after switching to carrierwave, so at this point you know more than I am. Good luck!

Comment: I been having this issue for hours when using paperclip to upload CSS files from the filesystem.  Tried everything until I ran into this.  Life saver!

Comment: Could you please post your final (working) code?

Comment: @Jason almost 2 years after and I haven't found a better solution yet. It is possible that the gem was updated since then, but I haven't checked it.  `self.file.send :initialize_storage` is still working